# If you `source` another file, `trap INT` defined before won't work?

Tags: bash, bash-trap

If I place this on the top the Bash script, Control+C doesn't work.

```
exit-function() {
  echo "Hey hey!"
}    
trap exit-function INT
```

But if I put it few lines after, then Control+C is trapped.

**UPDATE**:

**If it's placed after `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`, then it works.**

So if you source another file, `trap INT` defined before won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the scripts that's sourced by the rvm script sets a `trap` which replaces the trap you set earlier. By setting one after the rvm script you're replacing the one it sets.

Comment: trap is overwritten after each cd!